# System missing data

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, missing-data

I'm currently struggling with my data.

My dependent variable has an N of 332, out of which 180 are system missing,   because of the routing in the questionnaire:

First question:  Have you taken in the past two years some substantial new machines into production?
Second question: How many percent of your budget did they account for?

So this means if people answered 'no' at the first question, they won't have answered the second question, and so they appear in the data list as system missing.
Do I need to do some imputations, like 0%, or code it as -99, or just leave as is? What would you recommend?

I want to test some hypotheses with this dependent variable through a multiple regression.

Comment: "*180 are system missing*" --- this appears to be package-specific terminology. Which package -- SPSS? Something else?

Comment: Yes SPSS19 Glen.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is clear that the underlying substantive variable (expenses) must be zero. You will get a zero-inflated data set this way, though, and will end up with a regression in which (0,0) point will be 180 cases out of 332. You would need to make your judgement as to whether you want to analyze

1. All the n=332 data in pooled regression;
2. The positive n=152 responses only;
3. Use a method that accounts for the zeroes explicitly, like tobit or a two-part model.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply!
They must be zero indeed.
Let's say I want to test the following hypothesis: R&D outsourcing (measured by % R&D spending that is done by partners) is positively related to the innovativeness of a firm ( measured by the % new products in the turnover).
What do you recommend? option 1, 2 or 3?

Comment: That's up to you to decide, I would decline recommending anything right now.

Comment: Ok that's a shame, but I can understand it.. Thanks anyway!
I really like this forum because of the expertise and quickness of response of the users. Keep doing the good work.